# Central Limit Theorem in a win, lose or stay the same scenario

Tags: probability, probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

So, I have this problem:

> Robert bets on a casino game where he estimates that he has a 0.45 probability of winning, a 0.5 probability of losing, and a 0.05 probability of being left with no profit or loss. 
> In each game she bets \$10, which implies that she can win \$10, lose \$10 or stay as he was, with the odds described. If Robert plays this game 100 times independently. What is the approximate probability that he ends up with more money than he started (assuming she has enough money for the first 100 plays)?

My attempt:
Let $X_i$ be the money he gains or losses in each round. And let $Y=X_1+...X_{100}$. Then I have
$$E(X_i)=10(.45)+(-10)(.5)+0(.05)=-.5$$
$$E(X_i^2)=10^2(.45)+(-10)^2(.5)+0^2(.05)=95$$
$$Var(X_i)=E(X_i^2)-E(X_i)^2=95-(-.5)^2=94.75$$
Then
$$E(Y)=100E(X_i)=-50$$
$$Var(Y)=100Var(X_i)=9475$$
Now, if I want to calculate the  probability that he ends up with more money than he started I have to calculate $P(Y>1000)$.
**My problem is when I apply the CLT because**
$P(Y>1000)=1-P(Y\leq1000)=1-P(\frac{Y+50}{\sqrt{9475}}\leq\frac{1000+50}{\sqrt{9475}})=1-\phi(10.78)$ And using a Standard Normal Table that is impossible.
So, any help, suggestion or ideas are welcomed and appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps I am misreading, but is it not enough that $Y>0$?  After all, $Y$ represents your profit/loss on the game so if $Y$ is positive...

Comment: I agree with @lulu.

Comment: I think you guys are right. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that each $X_i$ denotes the loss or gain of the person in the $i$-th game. You're denoting each loss by $(-10)$ , each gain by $(+10)$. So, as you have defined $Y = X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_{100}$ , the event that he gains some positive amount after $100$ games is $[Y > 0]$ , NOT $[Y > 1000]$.

Now, by CLT, $~Z :=\dfrac{Y + 50}{\sqrt{9475}} \stackrel{\text{approx}}{\sim} \text{N}(0,1)$ . Thus :
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(Y > 0) &= \mathbb{P}\left(Z > \frac{50}{\sqrt{9475}}\right)\\
&\approx 1 - \Phi\left(\frac{50}{\sqrt{9475}}\right)\\
&\approx 0.3037
\end{align*}

---

**NOTE :** In case you want, you may assume that the person is using $\$ 10$ for playing a game, you may denote the total gain and loss by $(+20)$ and $0$ respectively, and keep the value of $X_i$ to be $(+10)$ in case of a draw.

Under that setup, the expectation and variance of $Y$ will change, but the event whose probability you want to drive will be $[Y > 1000]$. However, the final answer will be the same.

Comment: I think it might be worth a continuity correction.  The exact probability of $P(Y>0)$ (up to rounding) seems to be $0.285973063$ while the probability of of breaking even is $P(Y=0)=0.03579279$ and your answer is close to the first plus half the second.  You would do better with $1 - \Phi\left(\dfrac{55}{\sqrt{9475}}\right) \approx 0.286026
$

Comment: @Henry Isn´t it $1 - \Phi\left(\dfrac{50.5}{\sqrt{9475}}\right)$?

Comment: @callculus Each step is $\pm10$ so half a step is of magnitude $5$

Comment: @Henry Tanks for the reply. Let´s say you have n i.i.d random variable, namely $X_i$ and $S_n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i$.  Then my calculation for large $n$ is $P(S_n\leq k)\approx\Phi \left(\frac{k+0.5-n\cdot \mu}{\sqrt{n\cdot \sigma^2}} \right)$ I´ve never seen it in a different way. So I'm confused.

Comment: @callculus  If each bet was $1$ then the mean would be $5$ and the variance $94.75$ and you could find with continuity correction $1 - \Phi\left(\dfrac{5.5}{\sqrt{94.75}}\right)$.  There is no reason to get a different answer just because the bets are $10$ times bigger: the bet sizes do not affect the probability

Comment: @Henry I don´t see why the continuity correction factor should be multiplied by 10.  We have $S_n\dot \sim \mathcal N(-50, 9475)$. This is the random variable for the money after n games. The amount of the bets is already regarded. So we just add $0.5$ for the continuity correction factor.

Comment: @callculus why do you choose $0.5$? Because it is halfway between $0$ and $1$? If so, why $1$ here when $10$ makes sense in the context of this question?